# Order wp_query by numeric custom field not working

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to sort the results of a wp_query by an ACF numeric field, but sorting whatsoever. Changed order from ASC to DESC but still the same.

```
$counter = 0;
WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
       'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'teams',
        'meta_key' => 'standings-points',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'DESC'
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts()) :   $query->the_post(); $counter++; ?>

<td style=""><?php echo $counter; ?></td>
<td style="text-align: left;"><?php the_title();?></td>
<td><?php the_field('standings-points');?></td>

<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); wp_reset_query();
```

Can someone point me to the right direction please?

Comment: does standing points contain intergers or strings representing numbers?

Comment: @David I would have asked the same question :)